# HttpContextAccesor is null after being called in a difference service where it was inject when using a custom component in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have looked into attribute splatting for a blazor component,which I havent defined its class as inheriting ComponentBase, but I have set up some property field to assign the html attributes,  and then whenever the HttpContextAccesor is injected(it loops through 3-4 times to be injected within the first services' constructor and only twice in the second service both, and then the method is called to consume an API from the first service, then when it finishes and the second Service is called the Context accessor is null

here is defined the custom component (child component )

```
<input   required="@InputParameters["required"]" max="@InputParameters["max"]" maxlength="@InputParameters["maxlength"]"  
       placeholder="@InputParameters["placeholder"]" size="@InputParameters["min"]"
       value="@InputParameters["value"]" min="@InputParameters["min"]" name="@NameInput"  />

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, object> InputParameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"required","required" },
        {"placeholder","text place holder" },
        {"size", 100 },
        {"maxlength",100 },
        {"max",100 },
        {"min",0 },
        {"value",null }
    };

    [Parameter]
    public string NameInput { get; set; }

}
```

here is the parent component

```
@page "/EditEmployee/{Id:int}"
@inherits EditEmployeeBase
@using SharedRazorClassLibrary.Components;
@using EmployeeManagement.Models; 
<h3>EditEmployee</h3>

<label>Time Elapsed: @ElapsedTime </label>
<EditForm Model="Employee" OnValidSubmit="SaveEmployeeDetails" OnInvalidSubmit="CheckErrors">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MultiParameterComponent InputParameters="@(new Dictionary<string, object> {
                                                {"size",120 },
                                                {"placeholder","Hello"},
                                                {"maxlength",500 },
                                                {"max",500 },
                                                {"min",1 },
                                                {"value",null }
                                            })" NameInput="CustomMultiInput"></MultiParameterComponent>
    <div class="form-group" row>
        <label for="@Employee.FirstName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText @bind-Value="Employee.FirstName"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Employee.FirstName)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" row>
        <label for="@Employee.LastName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText @bind-Value="Employee.LastName"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Employee.LastName)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" row>
        <label for="@Employee.DepartmentId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <CustomInputSelect @bind-Value="Employee.DepartmentId">
                @foreach (var dept in Departments)
                {
                    <option value="@dept.DepartmentId">@dept.DepartmentName</option>
                }
            </CustomInputSelect>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() =>Employee.DepartmentId)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="@Employee.Gender"> Gender </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <CustomInputSelect @bind-Value="Employee.Gender">
                @foreach (var gender in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)))
                {
                    <option value="@gender">@gender</option>
                }

            </CustomInputSelect>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" row>
        <label for="@Employee.DateOfBirth" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputDate @bind-Value="Employee.DateOfBirth" @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/YYYY"></InputDate>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="@Employee.Email">Email</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@Employee.Email"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>Employee.Email)" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <a href="/DeleteEmployee/@Employee.EmployeeId" @onclick="DeleteEmployee" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

</EditForm>
```

here are the Startup's service injection

```
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddAutoMapper((config) => {
        config.AddProfile(typeof(EmployeeProfile));
    });
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton<PathHelper>();
    //services.AddScoped<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<IEmployeeServices,EmployeeServices>();
    services.AddScoped<IDepartmentServices, DepartmentServices>();
    services.AddHttpClient<IEmployeeServices,EmployeeServices>().ConfigureHttpClient((sp, httpClient) => {
       

    });
```

so I wonder what could be causing that the second request makes the IHTTPContextAccesor interface to be null?

Comment: [Polite ]I see a form, with a `MultiParameterComponent` that doesn't look like it will work, and doesn't bind to anything.  Then a somewaht garbled question on HttpContextAccessor.  I don't see any connectiopn at the moment.  What are you using the HttpContextAccessor for.  How is it connected with the form?   I write lots of Blazor code, and I've very rarely  used the `HttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: I think you have an XY problem. Can  you please share why you want to use HttpContextAccessor?

Comment: @MayurEkbote i need to know if I am running a project with VS or VS Code, so the context accesor lets me know which ports it is using, tho It works fine if I remove the Custom input component

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I dont know but it only happens when I add this component to the EditForm,

Comment: So the issue is with `MultiParameterComponent`.  What are you trying to achieve with it, that one of the Blazor Input controls with a bit of formatting  can't do?  I'm not trying to be pedantic, just understand what you are trying to achieve. :-)

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis just testing the multiples parameter with a Dictionary I dont know why the IHttpContextAccessor is discarded after the first service finishes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The odd solution was injecting the Interface in the same order i had injected it on Startup.cs

first the HttpClient and then the IHpttpContextAccessor this way the DI seemed to work as expected, tho I am using the HttpAccessor as Transient because as scoped it throws an exception when it register the service at startup